# page not opening when click the post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I click my ticket it is not opening the specified page. While clicking the link of my ticket it shows in the link the correct ticket id, but the page is not opening. The error is:

> 404 not found

**Ticket.blade.php**

```
<tr>
  @foreach ($ticketsinfos as $ticketinfo)
  <td>IR-173049</td>
  <td>Dito</td> 
  <td>{{ $ticketinfo->companies->name }}</td>
  <td><a href="/tickets/show/{{ $ticketinfo->id }}">{{ Str::limit($ticketinfo->ticket_title, 50, '...') }}</a></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button">Action Needed<br></button><br></td>
  <td>Tako Kiknadze</td>
  <td>{{ $ticketinfo->created_at }}</td>
  <td>{{ $ticketinfo->updated_at }}</td>
  </tr>

  @endforeach  
</tr>
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\AdminsUserController;
//use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
//use App\Http\Controllers\CompaniesController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\TicketsController;
//use App\Models\AdminsUser;
//use App\Models\Companies;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|----------------------------------------------z----------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('/dashboard', DashboardController::class);

Route::resource('/tickets', TicketsController::class);

Route::resource('/admin/users', AdminsUserController::class);
// Route::resource('/companies', CompaniesController::class);

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

**Controller**

```
public function show(Tickets $tickets)
{
  $tickets = Companies::with('tickets')->get();
  $severities = Severities::with('severity')->get();
  $ticketsinfos = Tickets::with('companies')->findOrFail(2);
  return view('customer.index', compact($tickets))->with(['tickets' => $tickets])->with(['severities' => $severities])->with(['ticketsinfos' => $ticketsinfos]);

  //dd($ticketsinfos->toArray());
}
```

When I use 'dd' it works.

Comment: `$ticketsinfos = Tickets::with('companies')->findOrFail(2);`
Is there a ticket with the id 2 in your database?

Comment: yes  I check also in dd it works with dd but in code it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your return in controller

try this

```
return view('customer', compact('tickets', 'severities', 'ticketsinfos'));
```

Comment: Same 404 not found

Comment: what is your blade name and in which folder it is?
is it Ticket.blade.php or index.blade.php

Comment: where I want to open it in new page name is customer.blade.php

Comment: than change the return to customer instead of customer.index

Comment: all blade are in views folder

Comment: i have edit my answer please check

Comment: customer is folder where is index.blade.php your answer is not correct. now I edit my index.blade.php and added to my form $ticketsinfos->id and now it shows me this error : Trying to get property 'created_at' of non-object

Comment: {!! Form::model(['method'=>'GET', 'action'=>'App\Http\Controllers\TicketsController@show', $ticketsinfos->id]) !!}

Answer (score 0):

Your having a problem because there is no defined route `tickets/show/{{ $ticket->id }}`. Since you are using route resource if you want to show the `ticket` with the given id you need to use `tickets/{{ $ticket->id }}` or using the `route()` helper. `{{ route('tickets.show', $ticket->id) }}

**Tip  :** Its easier to use the `route()` helper than using the the raw `url` of the path when accessing `named routes`, since you will not be confused when passing a parameter for the `route`. Example `{{ route('tickets.show', $ticket->id) }}` will generate the `url` as `tickets/1`